# unified_thread fql table available to public or not?

Tags: facebook-fql

I see facebook removed the banner from the [unified_thread documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_thread/) (which previously stated it was for developers accounts only) but I still get the "must be a developer" error.  Am I doing something wrong, or did FB just remove it by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

My testing shows a "ERROR: Error 298 You must be a developer of the application".

I assume they removed it by mistake, because other pages, such as [the Graph API Thread documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/) still shows the message.

Comment: This was an error. The banner has been replaced. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: @DhirenPatel - any idea when it will become available?